# How does one train a list of models in Torch?

Tags: python, scope, pytorch, torch

I am trying to train a list of torch neural network models. I am using a list because I want to have any number of models, and be able to iterate through the list. I am currently trying to

```
for i in range(len(model_list)):

    old_model = model_list[i]

    new_model = train_model(old_model, data) # train_model take a model, trains it, and returns it

    model_list[i] = new_model
```

However I am getting some kind of scope problem, since the models in the list do not update their parameters. I assume it has something to do with the model I am updating being some kind of clone, though I do not understand why returning the model has no effect. My training code looks like this:

```
def train_model(model, data):
    model_optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())
    model_output = model(data)
    model_loss = criterion(model_output, target) # lets just say target we get from data
    model_loss.backward()
    model_optimizer.step()

    return model
```

I don't see why code like this would not work, however the models in the list are not updating (after checking their coeffficients), and the loss does not change. Is this some kind of scope problem with regard to the models or their parameters? Or is there some other problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your current train_model function is only computing the loss and updating the weights of the models only for one iteration as you return the model always.

So, I suggest you to modify this function in order to train the models for X epochs before returning the model.

**Suggested Code**:

```
def train_model(model, data):
    model_optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        for data in train_loader:
            model.zero_grad()
            model_output = model(data)
            model_loss = criterion(model_output, target) # lets just say target we get from data
            model_loss.backward()
            model_optimizer.step()

    return model
```

Comment: This seems to be a different use case. In this one, you're missing the `model_optimizer.zero_grad()`.